# practical effect of not validating FKs in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key

I need to add a foreign key definition to a very large table in Postgres.  (Let's assume for the moment that I'm positive that every FK value is actually valid.)

I know that I can specify `NOT VALID` in order to prevent Postgres from taking aggressive locks on the table while validating the foreign key.  Then I can go back "at leisure" and run `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT` as a cleanup.

What if I never bothered going back to run `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT`?  Is there any practical effect of not doing so?

Comment: I validate FK when creating table with "job_co int references co(co_id)". I am not sure if this has anything to do with your question though.

Comment: Well, the practical effect obviously is that you could have some data in your database that violate the constraint. Usually the point of a constraint is to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

It is conceivable that the planner could use valid foreign key constraints to optimize query plans.  I don't think that it does that today, though. I know people had been working on such things, but I don't think anything has been accepted into released code, or is likely to be in the near future.